# How can I check type of this objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I wanna check type of obj below.

Q1.

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
is actually
arr = {
  0: "a",
  1: "b",
  2: "c"

}
```

Is this right?

Q2.
My object is

```
const myObjects = {
  "1111": {
    isField: true,
    mySet: ["one", "two"] // this is Set
  },
  "2222": {
    isField: false,
    mySet: ["one"] // this is Set
  },
}
```

Type of arr(Q1) is array in typescript.
Then, what is type of myObjects(Q2) ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `typeof` operator to determine the type of anything in javascript.

`typeof myObjects` will be "object"

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)